# problema con .htaccess con mi route me muestra index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, router

estaba realizando un route en mi pc local todo funciona perfectamente pero al momento de subirla al hosting presenta el problema de que tengo que colocar index.php/pelicula para que me aparezca la lista pero no me reconoce el css y cuando quito el index.php no me reconoce nada ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^pelicula/([a-zA-Z/]+)/([a-zA-Z/]+)/$ /index.php/pelicula=$1$2 [L]
```

route.php:

```
<?php

    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $request = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $request = explode('-',$request[2]);

    $_USER_ID = $request[2];

    $idcate = $request[1];


    switch ($request[0]){
        case '' :
            require 'View/sliderv3.php';
            break;
        case 'pelicula' :
            require 'vistas/viewflim.php';
            break;
    case '404' :
        require 'vistas/404.php';
        break;
    default:
        http_response_code(404);
        require 'vistas/404.php';
        break;
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Conseguiste solucionarlo?

Comment: no amigo si podrías ayudarme te lo agradecería

Comment: ¿Que hosting tienes? Quizás pueda ser de ayuda.

Comment: utilizo Cpanel amigo

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que tienes tu archivo .htaccess en el servidor y que no tienes dos archivos .htaccess? Por si acaso.

Comment: si claro tengo 1 solo no tengo mas

Comment: ¿En tu .htaccess has usado DirectoryIndex index.php? Estoy contemplando posibilidades y quizás alguien con más experiencia pueda ayudar, puede que sea algo   que no esté bien en cpanel.

Comment: Mmmm no creo que sea el hosting ya que es mi proveedor de confianza tanto como mis hosting como los de mis cliente los compro ahí y nunca me a dado problemas con relacion ah .htaccess asi que no creo que sea mi hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a quitar el slash "/" en /index.php, al principio del rewrite rule, te doy un ejemplo:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^pelicula/([0-9a-zA-Z-_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-_-]+)$ index.php?pelicula=$1$2 [L]

RewriteBase /
```

Comment: igual mano.. no me reconoce el url